# Cloudinary direct upload documentation example is not clear

Tags: javascript, django, cloudinary

In [Cloudinary Django SDK documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_and_video_upload) for direct from browser uploading it gives example below for `direct_upload_complete` view.

```
@csrf_exempt
def direct_upload_complete(request):
  form = PhotoDirectForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    ret = dict(photo_id = form.instance.id)
  else:
    ret = dict(errors = form.errors)

  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ret), content_type='application/json')
```

Immediately after this example it says *Having stored the image ID, you can now display a directly uploaded image in the same way you would display any other Cloudinary hosted image:* and gives template code example as follows:

```
{% load cloudinary %}      
{% cloudinary photo.image format="jpg" width=120 height=80 crop="fill" %}
```

I am confused by this template code example because it does not relate at all to the Django view code which has response name `ret`. Screenshot of documentation is below.

[image]

What would I need to do to use Javascript to create a variable from the JSON object named `ret` and display it on the template page?

Below is Javascript I am using on the example's `upload_prompt.html` template. It works fine, returning a thumb of uploaded image and some Cloudinary data that show after image is uploaded (on `cloudinarydone` event).

But I also want to get the uploaded photo's Model id to create a link to the photo using the id.

Where in below Javascript can I get the `photo_id` key value from the JSON object named `ret`?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#direct_upload input[type="file"]')
        .cloudinary_fileupload({
            dropZone: '#direct_upload',
            start: function (e) {
                $('.status').text('Starting upload...');
            },
            progress: function (e, data) {
            // $('.status').text('Uploading...');
                $(".status").text("Uploading... " + Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total) + "%");            
            },
            fail: function (e, data) {
            $(".status").text("Upload failed");
            }
        })
        .on('cloudinarydone', function (e, data) {
            $('.status').text('Updating backend...');
            $.post(this.form.action, $(this.form).serialize()).always(function (result, status, jqxhr) {
                $('.status').text(result.errors ? JSON.stringify(result.errors) : status);
            });
            var info = $('<div class="uploaded_info"/>');
            $(info).append($('<div class="image"/>').append(
                $.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, {
                    format: data.result.format, 
                    width: 150, 
                    height: 150, 
                    crop: "fill"
                })
            );               
            $(info).append($('<div/>').append('image/upload/' + data.result.path));
            $('.uploaded_info_holder').append(info);

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why did you think those two things are related? `direct_upload_complete` is for uploading and saving the image. `ret` is the status of that save operation. That has nothing to do with displaying the image, which you do separately by referring to the model instance you saved it to.

Comment: First, they are related prosaically in the documentation. Second, `direct_upload_complete` not only uploads and saves, it sends response. That response contains uploaded photo's model id. I want to access that model id so I can use it refer to it in template. Are you able to describe how to do that in template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brian Luk at Cloudinary Support, getting `photo_id` value is done in template's javascript `POST` request callback.

Maybe there are betters ways to do this, but I simply created variable `photoid` and then used that variable to create Photo model url.

```
$.post(this.form.action, $(this.form)
    .serialize()).always(function (result, status, jqxhr) { 
    $('.status').text(result.errors ? JSON.stringify(result.errors) : status);
var photoid = JSON.stringify(result.photo_id);

$(info).append($('<div/>').append('<a href="/photo/' + photoid + '/">link</a>'));
```